# "pop bottles all night" - slang or valid term?

Tags: slang, expressions

I know the meaning of "pop bottles all night" - drink all night long.

My question is - is this valid term, or slang invented by the person who wrote [the song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6XkrXu7mWc&feature=related)?

Comment: If you understood what it meant then the term was _successful_. The idea of _popping bottles_ to mean _opening bottles_ is common enough that it shouldn't cause too much confusion. To do something _all night_ is an established term. Combining the two makes sense to me.

Comment: @MrHen Actually I had to Google it, it wasn't clear on just hearing this. What you say makes sense though, thanks!

Comment: It should probably be noted that, while it's clear in the context of the song, the term "pop bottles" by itself is a little ambiguous.  It could mean "to open bottles" or it could mean "bottles of soda-pop".

Answer (score 2):

In this case pop means to

> verb: burst open with a sharp, explosive sound

So, *pop bottles all night* means *open bottles all night*.

It is not slang, though it is a metaphor (assuming you are correct that the author actually meant drink all night).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he/she meant drinking all night, can't see any reason to just open bottles without drinking their contents. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, it's a poem/song, the whole quote might have been: '*pop bottles all night / but none could I drink*'; in this case it would not have been a metaphor. Also, could have been a song about waitress, etc... The link to the actual song points to youtube, so can't read it...